# node.js stylus imports automatic rebuild, expire?

Tags: javascript, css, import, node.js, stylus

How do I get stylus to rebuild the css (including imports) automatically upon node restart and append the timestamp?

The problem as schaermu puts it:

> My stylus stylesheets were always
>   recompiled, with one exception: when
>   using the @import directive, the
>   imported stylesheet was NOT recompiled
>   when a change was noticed. For that
>   case, i always had to manually delete
>   the stylesheet for a full re-compile.

edit:
there's an issue:
https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/issues#issue/168

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i was building my own jade/stylus based apps, i used [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) for development. It auto-restarts on any filechanges (after considering an ignore list, see the docs).

My stylus stylesheets were always recompiled, with one exception: when using the **@import** directive, the imported stylesheet was NOT recompiled when a change was noticed. For that case, i always had to manually delete the stylesheet for a full re-compile.

But in all other cases, rebuilding the stylesheets worked like a charm.

P.S. i assume you are using express as your framework of choice, my experience is based on that.

Comment: Ahh thanks for clarification, most of my work is currently in the imported files, so that's what I need to change

Comment: fixed by TJ Holowaychuk after a bit of whining :)

Comment: ah, awesome...didn't notice yet :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using express or any connect based web framework you can use my forked compiler middleware (TJ closed my pull request so I think this will never get into the master).

https://github.com/masylum/connect/commit/6ab47b191a1ede91eae90b1608a61f0a7397b082

This adds the option to force autocompilation of CSS files.

Comment: Thanks for that, I don't actually need recompile on every request i'm using run.js which checks for changes. The problem is as schaermu says, I just need for it to check for imports too. I might be doing something wrong but I don't believe your change will fix the import issue. I think imports somehow works differently...

Comment: the compiler middleware looks for mtimes. If you have a `A.less` file that does an `import` of a `B.less` file, when you change the second one, the mtime of `A.less` will remain the same so it will not be recompiled. IMO, when developing you don't care about recompiling everytime. In production you will never compile any less file and use the generated CSS instead.